# readin prefix file error

Tags: c#, text

I have code that works properly reading a csv file as shown:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.csv").Select(a => a.Split(',')).ToList();
```

I want to rewrite this statement to read all files in the folder by prefix.

```
var lines = Directory.GetFiles("prefix*.csv").Select(a => a.Split(',')).ToList();
```

This code does not work due to the invalid * character in the path name.  I know I can do something similar to this with fileinfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles()` just gets the filenames, it doesn't read the lines.

try something like

```
var lines = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "prefix*.csv").Select(
            fn => File.ReadAllLines(fn).Select(a => a.Split(',')).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: oh well then I am definitely doing something wrong any ideas how I could fix

Comment: fn => File.ReadAllLines("fn") should be  fn => File.ReadAllLines(fn)  thank you prefect solution

Answer (score 1):

The pattern matching has to be used a second parameter, like this:

`var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "prefix*.csv");`